# How to access the same scope of a variable in the next function?

Tags: typescript, angular2-services

```
import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';

export class GitGrabService implements  OnInit {
  url;
  ngOnInit() {
}
getUsername(name: string) {
  this.url = 'http://api.github.com/users/' + name + '/repos';
  this.sendUrl();
}

sendUrl(): string {
  return this.url;
  }
}
```

Here when I'm trying to access the sendUrl() in another service, and if I try to print it, it shows up as undefined.

```
import {GitGrabService} from './gitGrab.service';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Headers, Http} from '@angular/http';
@Injectable()
export class GitRepoService {
 // public url;
  constructor(private  gitgrabService: GitGrabService,
              private  http: Http) {}

  fetchRepo() {
    console.log(this.gitgrabService.sendUrl());/// This shows up as undefined.
    return this.http.get(this.gitgrabService.sendUrl());
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `@Injectable()` decorator in the `GitGrabService`, otherwise you will not be able to create an instance of it in your other service.

Comment: True. But since I have added it in the GitRepoService, I should be able to print the return value in the console.

Comment: Your `this.url` value is initially undefined, so basically `this.gitgrabService.sendUrl()` will return an undefined value if you don't execute the `this.getUsername()` method first, cause you're loging the execution of `sendUrl`.